# Masonry items overlap sometimes

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-masonry

I'm having a strange problem. Sometimes post loaded via ajax stack/overlap in between. I've tried all the methods but nothing works. Please watch the screenshot.

My code is:

```
    var currentlyloading = false;
    $(document).on("click", ".next a", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        if(!currentlyloading) {
        currentlyloading = true;
            $(this).addClass('loading-icon').removeClass('static').text('LOADING...');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: $(this).attr('href') + '#latest',
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(out){
                    result = $(out).find('#latest .item');
                    nextlink = $(out).find('#pagination a').attr('href');
            $(result).hide();
imagesLoaded( document.querySelector('#latest'), function( instance ) {
  console.log('all images are loaded');
                $('.contentWrap').append(result.fadeIn(300));
            $('.contentWrap').append(result).masonry('appended', result);
            $('.contentWrap').height("+=300");
}); //images loaded
            currentlyloading = false;
                    $('#pagination a').removeClass('loading').text('LOAD MORE');
                    if (nextlink != undefined) {
                        $('#pagination a').attr('href', nextlink);
                    } else {
                        $('#pagination').remove();
                    }
                } //success
            }); //ajax
        } //currentlyloading
   }); //document onclick
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `.contentWrap` is the container that masonry was applied to in the first instance. That being true, instead of:

```
$('.contentWrap').append(result).masonry('appended', result);
```

Try:

```
$('.contentWrap').masonry('appended', result.toArray());
```

Your original code will have either been appending the new elements twice, or perhaps the `appended` method was failing due to passing in a jQuery wrapped collection of elements.

Using `.toArray()` converts the jQuery wrapped collection to a plain array of elements, which according to the [docs](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#appended), is an acceptable format for the argument.

Comment: Yes you're right `.contentWrap` is the container at which masonry is applied. I've tried `toArray()` It didn't work either.

Comment: Try also removing `$('.contentWrap').append(result.fadeIn(300));` before that line – didn't spot a third append in there. I think you were appending the new content three times?